# asp.net mvc templates seem to be missing from community edition 2017 visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2017, mvc

asp.net mvc templates seem to be missing from community edition 2017 visual studio.

going through the update install tool, I see that Web & Could(7) is completely checked, so I am supposed to have all the components.

see Screenshots.
That's all I see...

Any ideas?
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8DOB.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HorT.png)

Answer (score 0):

i got it.   It is the ASP.NET project.  There is no template in Visual Studio 5 that says MVC.net.  That is true only in older versions of .net